# I got an Error (ETIMEOUT) when I try to Post Data with Node.js into a HANA database

Tags: javascript, node.js, hana

I'm trying to post data to the HANA database with Node.js. Now I get this error:

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT `141.**.**.***:3051` at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]

My code looks like below. Where did I make a mistake? I'm an absolute beginner. I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

```js
var http = require('http');

var httpOptions = {
host: 'h05-d02.ucc.ovgu.de',                                                                        
path: '/gbi013/oData/SensorData.xsodata/SENSOR_DATA', method: 'POST',
port: 30515,  

headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Base64',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         }
};

updateHANA(); 

function updateHANA() {
    var req = http.request(httpOptions).on('error', function(err){ console.error(err); });
   
    var jsonData = {
        "ID": 13,
        "TEMPERATURE": "22.99",
        "HUMIDITY": "33.33",
    };
    var strData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
    console.log(strData);
    console.log(req.statusMessage)                                                                
    req.write(strData);       
    req.end();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, I'd say the port you try to bind your service to `30515` in the `httpOptions` variable is wrong.
The error message could be interpreted in a way that the `http` module only considers the first 4 digits `3051` and fails to connect to it due to a timeout (which makes sense if there is no service listening on this port).

Your choice of port is odd, too. It looks very much like the `SQL`communcation port of a default tenant database in HANA (if the system's instance number is `05`).

So, maybe you want to try this with a more "traditional" service port, like `80` or `8080` first and if that works you can check what is blocking you from using port `3051` (could also be e.g. a firewall blocking the port).